# Replace Paint Event C#

Tags: c#, gdi+, nullreferenceexception

I'm working with layered forms and I found a great example in Visual Basic .NET but came across a problem converting the source to C#. The Visual Basic.NET implementation uses the shadows modifier to effectively replace the Form Class' *Invalidate()* method and then does the same for the Paint event.

> Public Shadows Event Paint(ByVal G As Drawing.Graphics)

```
Public Shadows Sub Invalidate()
    Dim B As New Drawing.Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height)
    Dim G As Drawing.Graphics = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(B) : G.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    RaiseEvent Paint(G)

    G.Dispose()
    SetBits(B)
    B.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I converted the code to C# so it looks like the following:

```
public new event PaintEventHandler Paint;

public new void Invalidate()
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(g, Rectangle.Empty));

        g.Dispose();
        SetBits(b);
        b.Dispose();
    }
```

But when the method is invoked I receive a *NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I also tried a different implementation, but received the same exception.

```
    public delegate void PaintEventHandler(Graphics g);
    public event PaintEventHandler Paint;
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for null before invoking the event:

```
if (Paint != null)   
    Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(g, Rectangle.Empty));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try that actually but my concern was that after placing a break point on the statement that invokes the event, it was never executed. Which meant to be that I need to stop the paint event from being null, am I wrong? How can I do that please.

Comment: The paint event is there to notify anyone who registers an interest that the paint has occurred.  If no one has registered an interest, then the event ref will be null.  The checking of this in the VB example would have been handled automatically within the RaiseEvent call.

Comment: Your last comment makes perfect sense. Thankyou.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

by default, your `Paint` event dose not contain any functions. you well need to add a few in order to run this.

```
Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
```

where i declare:

```
void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

---

what you should do in your program is to call the function `onPaint()` or, better, to add your function to the `Paint` event instead of overriding it.